# parse app names and generate string for each type

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have below app names and they are categorized by each type as shown below:

```
#Below is for `app_kop_az1` type
app_kop_az1_hello
app_kop_az1_world
app_kop_az1_laguna
app_kop_az1_jolla

#Below is for `app_kop_az2` type
app_kop_az2_depot
app_kop_az2_friday
app_kop_az2_curad
app_kop_az2_daily

#Below is for `app_toy_az1` type
app_toy_az1_users
app_toy_az1_web
app_toy_az1_metrics
app_toy_az1_advert

#Below is for `app_toy_az2` type
app_toy_az2_exper
app_toy_az2_views
app_toy_az2_access
app_toy_az2_sas

#Below is for `app_wer_az1` type
app_wer_az1_dart
app_wer_az1_logical
app_wer_az1_trojan
app_wer_az1_table

#Below is for `app_wer_az2` type
app_wer_az2_cache
app_wer_az2_desco
app_wer_az2_peeko
app_wer_az2_loopo
```

So I have total 6 types as shown below:

```
app_kop_az1
app_kop_az2
app_toy_az1
app_toy_az2
app_wer_az1
app_wer_az2
```

Now I need to store above data in such a way so that at the end I can generate a String like this. For each type, I need to make five lines and each of those lines will be the app name for the other types (not including the one we are working on).

```
if_process_look app_kop_az1.* then add_pc pc_kop_az2 app_kop_az2_depot app_kop_az2_friday app_kop_az2_curad app_kop_az2_daily
if_process_look app_kop_az1.* then add_pc pc_toy_az1 app_toy_az1_users app_toy_az1_web app_toy_az1_metrics app_toy_az1_advert
if_process_look app_kop_az1.* then add_pc pc_toy_az2 app_toy_az2_exper app_toy_az2_views app_toy_az2_access app_toy_az2_sas
if_process_look app_kop_az1.* then add_pc pc_wer_az1 app_wer_az1_dart app_wer_az1_logical app_wer_az1_trojan app_wer_az1_table
if_process_look app_kop_az1.* then add_pc pc_wer_az2 app_wer_az2_cache app_wer_az2_desco app_wer_az2_peeko app_wer_az2_loopo

if_process_look app_kop_az2.* then add_pc pc_kop_az1 app_kop_az1_hello app_kop_az1_world app_kop_az1_laguna app_kop_az1_jolla  
if_process_look app_kop_az2.* then add_pc pc_toy_az1 app_toy_az1_users app_toy_az1_web app_toy_az1_metrics app_toy_az1_advert
if_process_look app_kop_az2.* then add_pc pc_toy_az2 app_toy_az2_exper app_toy_az2_views app_toy_az2_access app_toy_az2_sas
if_process_look app_kop_az2.* then add_pc pc_wer_az1 app_wer_az1_dart app_wer_az1_logical app_wer_az1_trojan app_wer_az1_table
if_process_look app_kop_az2.* then add_pc pc_wer_az2 app_wer_az2_cache app_wer_az2_desco app_wer_az2_peeko app_wer_az2_loopo

if_process_look app_toy_az1.* then add_pc pc_kop_az1 app_kop_az1_hello app_kop_az1_world app_kop_az1_laguna app_kop_az1_jolla
if_process_look app_toy_az1.* then add_pc pc_kop_az2 app_kop_az2_depot app_kop_az2_friday app_kop_az2_curad app_kop_az2_daily
if_process_look app_toy_az1.* then add_pc pc_toy_az2 app_toy_az2_exper app_toy_az2_views app_toy_az2_access app_toy_az2_sas
if_process_look app_toy_az1.* then add_pc pc_wer_az1 app_wer_az1_dart app_wer_az1_logical app_wer_az1_trojan app_wer_az1_table
if_process_look app_toy_az1.* then add_pc pc_wer_az2 app_wer_az2_cache app_wer_az2_desco app_wer_az2_peeko app_wer_az2_loopo

if_process_look app_toy_az2.* then add_pc pc_kop_az1 app_kop_az1_hello app_kop_az1_world app_kop_az1_laguna app_kop_az1_jolla
if_process_look app_toy_az2.* then add_pc pc_kop_az2 app_kop_az2_depot app_kop_az2_friday app_kop_az2_curad app_kop_az2_daily
if_process_look app_toy_az2.* then add_pc pc_toy_az1 app_toy_az1_users app_toy_az1_web app_toy_az1_metrics app_toy_az1_advert 
if_process_look app_toy_az2.* then add_pc pc_wer_az1 app_wer_az1_dart app_wer_az1_logical app_wer_az1_trojan app_wer_az1_table
if_process_look app_toy_az2.* then add_pc pc_wer_az2 app_wer_az2_cache app_wer_az2_desco app_wer_az2_peeko app_wer_az2_loopo

if_process_look app_wer_az1.* then add_pc pc_kop_az1 app_kop_az1_hello app_kop_az1_world app_kop_az1_laguna app_kop_az1_jolla
if_process_look app_wer_az1.* then add_pc pc_kop_az2 app_kop_az2_depot app_kop_az2_friday app_kop_az2_curad app_kop_az2_daily
if_process_look app_wer_az1.* then add_pc pc_toy_az1 app_toy_az1_users app_toy_az1_web app_toy_az1_metrics app_toy_az1_advert
if_process_look app_wer_az1.* then add_pc pc_toy_az2 app_toy_az2_exper app_toy_az2_views app_toy_az2_access app_toy_az2_sas
if_process_look app_wer_az1.* then add_pc pc_wer_az2 app_wer_az2_cache app_wer_az2_desco app_wer_az2_peeko app_wer_az2_loopo

if_process_look app_wer_az2.* then add_pc pc_kop_az1 app_kop_az1_hello app_kop_az1_world app_kop_az1_laguna app_kop_az1_jolla
if_process_look app_wer_az2.* then add_pc pc_kop_az2 app_kop_az2_depot app_kop_az2_friday app_kop_az2_curad app_kop_az2_daily
if_process_look app_wer_az2.* then add_pc pc_toy_az1 app_toy_az1_users app_toy_az1_web app_toy_az1_metrics app_toy_az1_advert
if_process_look app_wer_az2.* then add_pc pc_toy_az2 app_toy_az2_exper app_toy_az2_views app_toy_az2_access app_toy_az2_sas
if_process_look app_wer_az2.* then add_pc pc_wer_az1 app_wer_az1_dart app_wer_az1_logical app_wer_az1_trojan app_wer_az1_table
```

I thought of making a `Map<String, List<String>>` where key will be type name and value will be list of app names for that type but I am confuse then how to use this map to generate above string line by line for each type? Is it even the right way using map like this?

**Note:** I am working with Java 7 as of now.

Comment: Showcase what you tried so far

Comment: Basically I loaded all the app data in the map as I was talking about but from there I am confuse on how to use that map to generate these strings line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it using below code structure:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = ... // create data here

List<String> result = myMap.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .map(e -> {
    String s = "if_process_look " + e.getKey() + ".* ";
    // here you can do internal loop over e.getValue() and add what you want
    //   and concatenate it into one line text
    return s;
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but there are many other ways to do it.

Comment: I forgot to add, I am still using Java 7 so cant use Java 8 as of now. Also for each type when I generate 5 lines for other types, I need to make sure I dont add apps for the one I am working on.

Comment: Also this won't work I think because for each key I need to get values for other keys as well while generating the string

Comment: are you still around?